# Ping().Send causes lag

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm fairly new to C# and programming as a whole.

I decided to make a small application that would measure out the ping times to a couple of big websites so it is easy to see when I have connection problems...
Now my problem is that every time the program sends a ping request the whole program freezes and often crashes.

This is the code that I am using:

```
long Google = new Ping().Send("google.com").RoundtripTime;
```

Comment: That's because you're calling it synchronously, use the async method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144961(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your application freezes because the ping request is being performed on the same thread that displays your user interface. The application is therefore waiting for the response of the ping to be received before it can continue on doing other things. The longer it takes the ping to respond, the longer the application will be in a locked up state.

If you switch to using the [`Ping.Async()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144961(v=vs.110).aspx) method, the actual Ping request can be done in the background and therefore not interfer with the UI, like so:

```
long Google = -1;
var ping =  new Ping();
ping.PingCompleted += (s,a) => Google = a.Reply.RoundtripTime;
ping.SendAsync("google.com",null);
```

However, you will still have to make your application update its UI with the new value when the response comes back. The above example only will only update the local `Google` variable with the result of the ping, but your UI thread will not know that the value has been changed.

How exactly you do that will depend a little on what framework (Winforms, WPF, Console) is powering your UI, and how you have setup your UI, which you haven't really specified in your question.

Comment: I seem to be getting -1 as a result.

Comment: @JariSchockaert, this answer is not complete code. Because the ping is now being done as asynchronous call, the code will not automatically wait for the result to be returned and hence the initial value of -1 is not updated yet. The example in the linked [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144961(v=vs.110).aspx) has a correct way to wait for the result (but not necessarily the best depending on your own intent). Follow that example instead.